# Virtualbox Bridged network ethernet cable disconnecting

Tags: 12.04, networking, virtualbox, ethernet, static-ip

I’m trying to connect to a ethernet device (like a scanner/printer) to a guest Ubuntu 12.04 running on Virtualbox 4.3.12. The scanner is connected to the Mac Pro directly over ethernet cable.
Problems faced:
1) The ethernet connection gets disconnected and the ip needs to be set again to reconnect.
2) How to permanently set a static ip to the bridge adaptor connection?

System:
Host: Mac Pro running OS X 10.9.3
Guest: Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit
Virtualbox settings: Bridged adaptor
Device connected on ethernet (scanner) demands:
the network settings of the Ethernet adapter set from automatic IP address to manual IP address selection with:
IP address: 192.168.1.X   (here X can be 0 to 100)
Gateway: 255.255.255.0

In terminal (***TERMINAL_STATE 0***):

```
viki@c3po:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:b3:ed:c7  
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:feb3:edc7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4195220 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1800 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:651884753 (651.8 MB)  TX bytes:381818 (381.8 KB)
```

---

NOTE: There is no IP address in the line after eth0 . **Why?**

Later in terminal (***TERMINAL_STATE 1***):

```
viki@c3po:~$ sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.1
viki@c3po:~$ ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:b3:ed:c7  
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:feb3:edc7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2540914 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1454 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2995685395 (2.9 GB)  TX bytes:308913 (308.9 KB)
```

---

At this point, the ubuntu wireless network icon is passive (looks like a sector of a circle):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2hiq6P5ceD-WTJhMDJ1MlNwWlU/edit?usp=sharing

Within a minute or two, the wireless network icon starts blinking (the sector has waves in it):

Finally, in a few seconds, I get a warning Wired Network Disconnected - You are now offline :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2hiq6P5ceD-bFp2NjhxaE5EQTA/edit?usp=sharing

Now if I do a ifconfig, I get same response as ***TERMINAL_STATE 0*** mentioned earlier.

Later, if I set the ip again using `sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.1` then I get reconnected.

Comment: Ummm what does wireless network has to do with your eth0 connection? eth0 is your ethernet cable connection not wireless

Comment: I'm seeing some serious network flap on Virtualbox on a Windows 7 host.  This seems to be a recent regression.  See https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13839

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep managed /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` to see if network manager trying to DHCP an address and fails. On top of the whole wireless confusion  `sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.1` only sets ip temporary (until you reboot or restart the service) you need to set static IPs in `/etc/network/interfaces` like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```